# iPhone console process in standby mode

Tags: iphone, sockets, tcp, background, console

I develop console application for iPhone/iPad, which not planning to distribute in App Store.
My application do not use UIApplication class instance.

I use GDC (Grand Central Dispatch) for running periodic tasks.
Also I use setsockopt for setting 60 sec timeout for syscall read() from TCP socket.
When iPhone go to standby mode, no periodic tasks running, and read returns by timeout not after 60 seconds, but after 9-10 minutes.

I try using syscall alarm and signal for SIGALRM, but in standby mode this solution do not work.

I find Info.plist keys for some solutions, but I cannot use Info.plist, because my application is console (hidden from iPhone user).

Can You suggest me any solution or ways to find solutions?